# Solution Explorer doesnt show the folder although the folder is present in my local drive (local copy) Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mapping, solution-explorer, source-control-explorer

I have copied the source code from source control explorer to my local drive. the mapping is done and i am able to work on the code and build it. However, there are some files which doesnot show up in the Solution Explorer although it shows in the local copy of drive.

I tried to refresh it and i cannot get the correct folder structure in solution explorer. Any advice how to get it ??

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To see other files in the solution explorer click the "Show All Files" button as shown in the image below. This will allow you to see all the files in your project folder.

[image]

Right-click in each file you want to add and select "Include in project"

I hope this can help you.

Comment: And then the folders/files which are present in the file system tree but are not considered as part of the Project by Visual Studio will be shown having a "ghost icon" (dotted icon outline, with no area filling). --> To include one of these "ghost" files/folders into the Visual Studio Project, right click it and select "**Include in Project**" from the popup menu.

Comment: MacOS users, for what its worth, note that if you add folders or files via finder or wherever, you have to first deselect then reselect the "Show All Files" option for them to finally appear in the explorer... yikes