# Visual Studio 2015 can't find node_modules after npm i

Tags: visual-studio

A folder is not showing up in solution explorer, yet exists on hard drive as part of solution.

When created files through the command line I can't find them in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution Explorer doesnt show the folder although the folder is present in my local drive (local copy) Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440562/solution-explorer-doesnt-show-the-folder-although-the-folder-is-present-in-my-lo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On you solution explorer, click on the "Show All Files" icon, which is the second from the left.  Your "missing" files and folders will now show up, but will be grayed out.  Right-click on them and select "Include in Project".

Comment: did you just answer your own question?

Comment: lmao seems like he did