# Visual Studio not updating folders inside project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, directory, updates

I'm using C++ to create a virtual pet game that runs in the console and uses simple text files to store the pet information. I used this code to create the text file that stores the pet info, such as happiness, hunger, cleanliness, etc:

```
std::fstream petInfo;
petInfo.open("InternalFiles/PetStatus.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
```

This code works and creates the file, but Visual Studio does not show the .txt file in the folder. Here is my folder structure:

```
Solution
    Project
        Core (folder)
        InternalFiles (folder, this is where PetStatus.txt goes)
        Main.cpp (Main)
```

If I run the program and then open File Explorer and navigate to InternalFiles, I see the file there, but it doesn't show up in VS. Does anyone know a way to fix this? I tried right-clicking on the solution and clicking "Rescan Solution", but that did not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is File Explorer, not Solution Explorer, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @AndrewBota May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440642/980129) can help

Comment: @Manuel That link helped so much, but it did not solve my problem. For some reason, restarting VS seemed to fix it. Thank you!